# forfiles with exec() and spaces in the path

Tags: php, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, exec

I'm trying to recursively delete only sql files in a directory using forfiles in exec().

This is what I have:

```
$dir = date('D jS, M Y \a\t H-i a') ;

exec('forfiles /p "E:\Database Dump\\'.$dir.'\" /m *.sql /c "cmd /c del @file"') ;
```

However, it is saying that "@file" is not a argument/valid option when I run my PHP script in the command prompt.

I know it must be something to do with the spaces in the path name (I think!), and I have tried running it without quotes, escaping spaces with / and ^ but with no joy.

How can I do this?

---

Here's an echo:

```
forfiles /p "E:\Database Dump\Fri 9th, Nov 2012 at 10-36 am\" /m *.sql /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

Comment: did you just do a print_r() of 'forfiles /p "E:\Database Dump\\'.$dir.'\" /m *.sql /c "cmd /c del @file"' and looked at it?

Comment: You can more easily do the same with `for /f %f in ('dir $dir\*.sql /s/b') do del "%f"` -- replace `$dir` with the path. No need to dabble in `forfiles` and extra shells at all.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to do this is simply

```
del dir\*.sql /f /q
```

or to recurse through subdirectories use the `/s` switch.

No need for `forfiles` at all.